# how to send the values of javascript variables to other page through jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a function

```
    function postRequest(strURL)
    {
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: strURL,    
        success: function(data){
            updatePage(data);
         }  
    });  
     }
```

now i am using this function this way

```
function comment()
{
   var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value; 
   var y=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value; 
   var z=document.forms["myForm"]["message"].value; 
   alert("the name is " + x );
   postRequest("comment.php?name=" + x +"&email="+ y +"&message="+ z );
}
```

variables x,y,z are getting values from a form.alert function in last but one line is working well.but the i can not send the values to the comment.php

Comment: Does the AJAX request not happen at all, or are you not seeing the correct values in `comment.php`?

Comment: You might as well use HTTP GET, if all the information is passed in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function postRequest(server, dataToSend)
            {
                $.ajax({  
                    url: server,
                    data: dataToSend,
                    type: "POST",  //If you want to make a GET just change it here.
                    success: function(data){
                        //updatePage(data);
                        $("#result").append(data);
                    }
                });  
            }

            function comment(e)
            {
                var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value; 
                var y=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value; 
                var z=document.forms["myForm"]["message"].value; 
                postRequest("comment.php", {name : x, email : y, message:z }); //Send the url of the server, and the data
                //Stop the default form submit
                return false;
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#myForm').submit(comment);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="GET" action=".">
            <input type="text" name="name" /> <br />
            <input type="text" name="email" /> <br />
            <input type="text" name="message" /> <br />
            <input type="submit" value="search"/>
        </form>
        <div id="result">
            <h1>Data returned:</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's the code that looks more like what you showed to us, but I have some suggestion to improve the javascript code:

```
function postRequest(e)
            {
                $.ajax({  
                    url: "comment.php",
                    data: $('form#myForm').serialize(),
                    type: "POST",  //If you want to make a GET just change it here.
                    success: function(data){
                        //updatePage(data);
                        $("#result").append(data);
                    }
                });
                //Stop the default form submit
                return false;
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#myForm').submit(postRequest);
            });
```

If you still want to learn more about Ajax and javascript with jQuery in general you can take a look a this really good book:

http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html#chapter-7

Comment: can u please explain me this line...
 $('#myForm').submit(comment);
can we call a function "comment" like this??

Comment: with $('#myForm').submit(comment) you are binding the submit event to the form, and if you check in the jquery api  http://api.jquery.com/submit/ you can pass a handler function to it, in this case our handler function is the comment function which is treated as a "callback" that means that our handler function wont be called at the assignment, it will be called at the execution of the submit event, you can take a deeper look at how the events work  http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html#chapter-5 if my answer solved your questions please feel free to accept it clicking at the accept button